# Is there any function among the LDAP functions to get user information without using ldap_search?

Tags: c++, windows, active-directory, ldap

I want to know the user details from AD.

I already tried the `ldap_search` function.

Is there any other function for getting user info among the LDAP functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ldap_search`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is part of Windows' low level LDAP library.  You might want the easier to use COM interface [IADs and friends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @ Hall :But,i dont hve adspath value.how can i use IADS?

Comment: if ldap_search is easy enough for you - you don't need IADs.

Comment: @SanjuMonu Your question was about alternatives to `ldap_search`.  If you want help on using `ldap_search` or `IADs`, please post another question with exactly what you are trying to retreive from Active Directory.

Comment: @ Hall :i want to get user information(attrib values),but i have only username,password and domainname values...using ldap_search function `LDAP_REFERRAL` error occured.But i add user OU details in ldap_search option,it will succeed.So how can i get user information without specifying OU. or suggest any other function.

Comment: @SanjuMonu I'll be happy to answer this when you [post it as a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).